# Customer custom attribute not included in collection by default in edit account information

Tags: magento2.2, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I've created a custom customer attribute "Skype", for more detail you can visit here:-

http://nimb.ws/CrM0YF

I've displayed & saved(in the backend) successfully this attribute on the registration page.

but I want to add this attribute in customer edit account so that he can update this attribute.

**Here is the path:-**

```
app/design/frontend/Packagetheme/themename/Magento_Customer/templates/form/edit.phtml

 <div class="field">
            <label for="skype" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Skype')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="skype"  id="skype" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCustomer()->getSkype()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Skype')) ?>" class="input-text" >
            </div>
            </div>
```

But I'm not able to set value using(in customer collection custom attributes not included so I'm not able to set this value):-

```
<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCustomer()->getSkype()) ?>
```

I also tried using object manager but didn't get success.

**Here is My script:-**

**1-  CustomerSetup.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Customerform\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'skype',
            [
            'label' => 'Skype',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',


                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'input' => 'text',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'skype')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();

    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

**2- InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Customerform\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Allin\Customerform\Setup\CustomerSetup');
                $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



        }

    }
}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Do a indexing for a one more time. If you using extension then you  attribute then https://webkul.com/blog/add-extension-attribute-magento2/ then you need to use `$extAttributes =$block->getCustomer()->getExtensionAttributes();
 
$selectedShipping = $extAttributes->getSkype()`

Comment: thanks, can you please make it simpler? I I've updated my post, please review again.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in installer script of custom customer attributes :

```
$used_in_forms=array();
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $attribute->save();
```

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: Thanks for your input, I think I already included your input.I've added my script please review my post & let me reply for the same.